# How to give multiple submit buttons a unique and automated variable in PHP

Tags: php

If I am calling an undistinguishable amount of records from a database through a while loop, and with each record called a submit button is accompanied with it, how can I get each submit button to respond exclusively to its respective iterated record? A visual of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

In the logic behind this, each "Contact" button is linked to its adjacent profile. So, if I click on the "Contact" button next to "Lily," Lily's name is passed on to the next page. However, so far I am met with this:

[image]

Where no matter which "Contact" button I press, the name of the last iteration is passed on. In this case, even I clicked on "Lily"'s contact button, the name of the last iteration, "Jane", is passed on to the next page.

Here is the code I am stuck with:

list.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once( "./inc/connect.inc.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION["email_login"])) {
   header("location: index.php");
}
else {
}
?>

<?php
if ($searchST) {
while ($row = $searchST->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo '<form action="list.php" method="POST">';
  echo '<div class="z">';
  echo  '<div class="x">';
  echo    '<div class="y">';
  echo       '<div class="text_info">';
  echo           "<div id='input_titles'>C1</div><textarea readonly name='c1' id='a' rows='3' cols='54' maxlength='162' onCopy='return false' onDrag='return false' onDrop='return false' onPaste='return false' autocomplete='off'>".$row["c1"]."</textarea><br />";
  echo           "<div id='input_titles'>C2</div><textarea readonly name='c2' id='a' rows='3' cols='54' maxlength='162' onCopy='return false' onDrag='return false' onDrop='return false' onPaste='return false' autocomplete='off'>".$row["c2"]."</textarea><br />";
  echo           "<div id='input_titles'>C3</div><textarea readonly name='c3' id='a' rows='15' cols='54' maxlength='810' onCopy='return false' onDrag='return false' onDrop='return false' onPaste='return false' autocomplete='off'>".$row["c3"]."</textarea><br />";
  echo           "<div id='input_titles'>C4</div><textarea readonly name='c4' id='a' rows='2' cols='54' maxlength='108' onCopy='return false' onDrag='return false' onDrop='return false' onPaste='return false' autocomplete='off'>".$row["c4"]."</textarea>";
  echo       '</div>';
  echo       '<div class="visual_info">';
  echo           '<div class="p_pic_image">';
  echo              "<img src='".$row["pic"]."' id='p_pic'> ";
  echo           '</div>';
  echo           '<div class="country_and_name">';
  echo              "<textarea readonly name='country' id='country' rows='1' cols='14'>".$row["country"]."</textarea>";
  echo              "&nbsp".$row["first_name"];
  echo           '</div>';
  echo       '</div>';
  echo      '<form action="network.php" method="POST">';
  echo         '<input type="submit" name="message" id="message" value="Message">';
  echo      '</form>';
  echo    '</div>';
  echo  '</div>';
  echo '</div>';

  if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $carry = "SELECT `first_name` FROM `users`";
    $carryST = $con->query($carry);
    if($carryST) {
      while ($row = $carryST->fetch_assoc()) {
          $_SESSION['to_name'] = $row["first_name"];
          $_SESSION['to_id'] = $row["id"];

      }
    }

    $carryST->close();
    header("location: compose.php");
    exit();
  }
echo '</form>';

  }

}
  $searchST->close();
  } else {

  }
```

The page the name of a given profile is supposed to pass through(compose.php):

```
<html>
  <head>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<title>Compose</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/compose.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>‌
  </head>
</html>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <?php echo $_SESSION["to_name"]; ?>
      <?php echo $_SESSION["to_id"]; ?>
      <div class = "prep_stmt">Your message to <?php $_SESSION["to_name"]; ?>...</div>
    </header>
  <div id="back_to_inbox">
    <a href="mail.php"/>inbox</a>
  </div>
<div class="msg_input">
  <textarea id="textbox" name="body" rows="28" cols="96" maxlength="2604"></textarea>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).delegate('#textbox', 'keydown', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

  if (keyCode == 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var start = $(this).get(0).selectionStart;
    var end = $(this).get(0).selectionEnd;

    // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, start)
                + "\t"
                + $(this).val().substring(end));

    // put caret at right position again
    $(this).get(0).selectionStart =
    $(this).get(0).selectionEnd = start + 1;
  }
});
</script>
<div class="send_button">
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</div>
```

**Update**: I think a way for me to retrieve distinct values for each record coming out of the loop would be for me to somehow incorporate:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < j; $i ++)
```

or something of the sort. The source of my problem is because of the session variables, which are getting updated with each loop (which is why the highest id keeps getting sent forward).

**Update2**: Instead of the method I was thinking above, I've looked into another possibility of inserting a hidden input value carrying the id of each output under the  tags surrounding the submit button, and then on the receiving page, setting conditions to query from there:

```
      echo         '<form action="network.php" method="POST">';
      echo            '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" />';
      echo            '<input type="submit" name="message" id="message" value="Message">';
      echo         '</form>';
```

and the receiving page contains:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id']))
{
// run query to get first_name where the submitted record id matches
$toCD = "SELECT `first_name` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = intval($id)";
$toST = $con->query($toCD);
// make sure a row was return
if($toST->num_rows === 1)
{
    $row = $toST->fetch_assoc();
    echo  "<div class = 'prep_stmt'>Your message to".$_row["first_name"]."...</div>";
}
else
{
    // record id does not exist. Output error message
}
}
  ?>
```

Note that these are additions. Everything else from the original code is much the same. However, I am still not getting a output. Nothing shows up on the receiving page.

Answer (score 1):

At first have a look on form, you have to define form for individually for each person.

**Also**

You see `$_SESSION['to_name']` is assigning value respectively in time of looping and at the end of loop it set's the last value of the DB record . That's why you are getting last person's name all time.

Comment: Yes you are right. However, I will not know the exact number of people I will have so I need to find a way of automatically assigning a variable to each person (which I don't know PHP well enough to troubleshoot). Do you have a suggestion perhaps?

Comment: yes, i have. Do you have unique ID for each record?

Comment: Yes, each record is assigned a unique id. I've included a small update to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You need a form for each Contact so that when you click "contact" you then send the values associated with that contact.

Comment: That is what I elaborated on, but I need a solution good fellow

Comment: Ok. In your while loop. You need to create a form with the same action attr because when you submit your form the browser only considers the last name textfield(you re kind of overwritimg your textfield ny using the same name). Try this:

       while(..row ..... Fetch){
            echo '<form action="contact.php" method="post">;
          //echo details of the user
          //submit button
          //close the form for this entry
          echo '</form>';
      }

sorry i m on my mobile

Comment: You could use unique ids in your database table which you would use to lookup for each user

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and so far nothing has changed. However, I do understand better about what I am dealing with. It seems that only the last user is recognized while the previous users are somehow "de-activated." You didn't have to answer from your mobile but I thank you for your readiness to help.